# Merging synonomous tags: Gadgeteer & .Net Gadgeteer

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

[Gadgeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gadgeteer/info) and [.net-gadgeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-gadgeteer/info) are the same thing.